# slick slide in jquery website showing blank after last slide and then starting from begining

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider, slick.js

i have a website done in html, i have used slick slide to move some products in two sections, at a time i want to display 5 products and then loop it infinitely, i have 10 products exact for both sections, yet after the last product, its showing white space and then again starting from begining:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.customer-logos5').slick({
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 4500,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    slidesToScroll: 1,

    autoplaySpeed: 0,
    speed: 8000,
    infinite: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',

    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }, {
      breakpoint: 520,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

my live website is : [live](https://jewelit.in/)   section names Trendy collections and New arrivals, can anyone please tell me what could wrong in here, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is how to set the slick slider. What do you need exactly. It's your jquery code from above.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.your-class').slick({
      slidesToShow: 5,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      arrows: false,
      dots: false,
     
      autoplaySpeed: 0,
      speed: 8000,
      infinite: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      cssEase: 'linear',

      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      }, {
        breakpoint: 520,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      }]
    });
  });
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="your-class">
      <div>your content 1</div>
      <div>your content 2</div>
      <div>your content 3</div>
      <div>your content 4</div>
      <div>your content 5</div>
      <div>your content 6</div>
      <div>your content 7</div>
      <div>your content 8</div>
      <div>your content 9</div>
      <div>your content 10</div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: i updated my code with urs, still same issue

Comment: what do you need exactly. I don't understand your issue. Could you update your code please.

Comment: please check my live website, after the last slide, there is blank space and then again starts from first slide, i need to remove that blank space